# Which direction will the beam of electrons be deflected?

Tags: homework-and-exercises

[image: Electromagnetic question]

For D.C. sources like the one shown, do we apply Fleming's right hand rule or left hand rule? I derived my answer using Fleming's left hand rule in this case. If I am not mistaken, we use Fleming's right hand rule for A.C. motors only. I got C but the answer is B.

Comment: F's left hand rule gives you the direction of force on a moving charge in a magnetic field. If you apply it correctly here, you do get answer B. F's right hand rule gives you the direction of the induced emf in a moving conductor. With a little thought, it's quite possible to use a single rule to find both these directions, but Fleming devised the rules for electrical engineers, not for those more interested in the underlying theory.

Comment: @philipWood Thank you, I think i realised my misconception. I assumed that the charge only travels in the direction of the thumb(in its plane as well); but instead, it travels in a circular upward or downward motion(I think).

Comment: First finger Field: upwards on screen or page (applying right hand grip rule to the wires of the coil); seCond finger Current: from right to left as electrons are negative; Thumb Thrust into the page (or screen).

Comment: @philipwood Shouldn't North pole be at the top and South pole at the bottom? So first finger pointing downwards. Because current comes from the positive terminal(talking about conventional).

Comment: "Shouldn't North pole be at the top and South pole at the bottom?" Yes. "So first finger pointing downwards." No. Inside the coil the field goes from South to North. Remember that *magnetic* field lines are continuous closed loops. – 
Philip Wood
 59 mins ago

Comment: @philipwood Thank you, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D.C. source connected to solenoid will produce constant current, generating constant magnetic field (directed up in the solenoid and down outside the solenoid). The right direction of electron velocity equals left orientated current of positively charged particles, so if the current goes to the left anf field points down, the force will act to the page by the rule of vector product (according to Lorents law). You have to point your right hand fingers in to the current direction and make the field has to come in your palm, so the thumb will be looking into the page.